# can we use 6146 x 1536 px image on android table

Tags: image, android

I am developing game in android tablet I use platform 3.2 Api level 13, where I have to use background image 6146 x 1536 on every screen in png format, but problem is that I am getting error out of memory problem on loading application. Can we use this size image or any solution for that.

Comment: Why would you want to use a background image that size? Do you know any tablets of that resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a straightforward solution is "don't do that".

Depending on what the image is for, you should either break it down into sensibly sized tiles (for when you always display the image at a certain size and resolution, and want to scroll around) or create several different zooms of the same image, and break those down into tiles, too (to support zooming in and out and scrolling around). Only load the tiles you currently need into memory, etc.

If the image is neither zoomed or scrolled at any point, then you should have an image that is rather closer to the screen size that you might expect on an android device.